# Which one would you use when you need to emit events between siblings in vue? vuex? mixin?

Tags: vue.js

Hope you're all well.

Currently, I'm using Vuetify, Handsontable, Vue2-leaflet, and GeoJson to make our system's geo controlling menu.
However I'm still a junior and  the only one using this framework in the company. Also, vue community is very small in South-Korea so let me ask a one simple question. I've already asked them but no help so far.

What to use when you emit events(and data) between siblings?

Vuex?
Mixins?

Since my research says mixin is for constant typeof data, and use vuex for other cases, so i've tried, but my former colleague used eventbus to emit the almost all functions. Which made me kind of mad since it's a huge program and there are so many bugs.

Anyway, many thanks in advance.

edit:
We have 8 menu and over 50 sub-menus.
This communication between siblings is only for the 1 sub-menu, geo controlling.

I made
[GeoMain.vue] (parent - axios, and send out data to children) 
[GeoMap.vue] (child 1 - vue2-leaflet, geojson, added CRUD UI only(for link and node)), 
[GeoHotTable.vue] (child 2 - handsontable, displays link and node data. GeoMap is for frontend UI display only, all the functions are gonna be in this component. ex: when user clicked 'add node' button on GeoMap.vue, there's gonna be a new line on this GeoHotTable.vue's hot-table so they can add all the data within this table.)

Comment: Just use `vuex` if you have a lot of events or data that need to be shared between components. It's the go to state management solution for vue. `Mixin`s are meant for code reuse.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! Didn't think of 'reuse'.

Comment: I usually advise against direct communication between siblings; the parent should be in control of its children, but it depends on the situation (an event bus may be more appropriate).

Comment: Thanks, that's what I've read before but it's a huge program. and all those eventbuses that the former one made, are messed up so I have to re-write them all over again. I will try vuex and eventbus in case it's urgent .... ;)

Comment: If it is just the `events`, then event-bus is the way to go. 
It comes right out of the box with Vue, you do not have to install any other library for using it. 

If it is about state management, then it depends upon your usecase, basis on that you can decide whether to use `Vuex` or not.

Comment: so using eventbus is ok for a huge web as well? I've read a lot of articles and comments to not to use it for a big web, and the code that I have to deal with is kind of messed up because of it. I guess maybe it's a bad usage of former colleagues... though thanks a lot. I will use eventbus in cases where I only emit events! :)